# add the data every time the funtion is called into a array object of State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am having this handleCheckClick  funtion witch gets `Data`  i want to store the data into a state every time the handleCheckClick funtion is called so after many times handleCheckClick  is called the state should look like the  object array below

```
handleCheckClick = (e, stateVal, index) => {
  
    let prevState = [...this.state[stateVal]];
    prevState[index].positive = e.target.checked;
    console.log(index);
    this.setState({ [stateVal]: prevState });
    var date = moment(this.state.dateState).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const { id, checked } = e.target.dataset;
    console.log(stateVal);
    if (e.target.checked) {
      var checkbox = "True";
    } else {
      var checkbox = "False";
    }

    const Data = {
      boolvalue: checkbox,
      date: date,
      userid: id,
    };
   
 this.setState({ datastate : Data  });// something like this
   
  };
```

after many times the  handleCheckClick funtion is called the state must look like this

```
[
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "userid" : 6,
        "boolvalue" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "userid" : 5,
        "boolvalue" : false
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "userid" :7,
        "boolvalue" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "userid" : 11,
        "boolvalue" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 4,
        "boolvalue" : false
    }
]
```

pls create a codesandbox example

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-wind-mjfjh4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take your data and call `setState` using the existing data merged with the new `Data` object. The merging can be done using `...` (spread) operator. Here's the code with the relevant parts:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {

    handleClick = (e) => {
        // build up a new data object:
        if (e.target.checked) {
            var checkbox = "True";
        } else {
            var checkbox = "False";
        }

        const { id } = e.target.dataset
        var date = moment(this.state.dateState).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        const Data = {
            boolvalue: checkbox,
            date: date,
            userid: id,
        };

        // set the new state, merging the Data with previous state (accesible via this.state)
        // this creates a new array with all the objects from this.state.datastate and the new Dataobject
        this.setState({
            datastate: [...this.state.datastate, Data]
        })
   
    }

    // log the state on each update for seeing changes.
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('Component did update. State:', this.state)
    }

    // Rendering only a button for showcasing the logic.
    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // initialise an empty state
        this.state = {
            datastate: [],
            dateState: new Date()
        }
    }

}
```

#### Edit for removing an element when unchecked:

You can remove a certain element by its id in the `onClick` handler when the box is unchecked:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {

    handleClick = (e) => {

        // get id first.
        const { id } = e.target.dataset

        // if element is not checked anymore remove its corresponding data:
        if(e.target.checked === false) {
            // remove the element by filtering. Accept everything with a different id!
            const update = this.state.datastate.filter(d => d.userid !== id)
            this.setState({
                datastate: update
            })

            // end handler here..
            return

        }

        // if we get here, it means checkbox is checked now, so add data!
        var date = moment(this.state.dateState).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        const Data = {
            // it is better to keep the boolean value for later use..
            boolvalue: e.target.checked,
            date: date,
            userid: id,
        };


        // set the new state, merging the Data with previous state (accesible via this.state)
        // this creates a new array with all the objects from this.state.datastate and the new Dataobject
        this.setState({
            datastate: [...this.state.datastate, Data]
        })
   
    }

    // log the state on each update for seeing changes.
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('Component did update. State:', this.state)
    }

    // Rendering only a button for showcasing the logic.
    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // initialise an empty state
        this.state = {
            datastate: [],
            dateState: new Date()
        }
    }

}
```

Feel free to leave a comment

Comment: thanx for the answer this does work but can u help me with one more problem

Comment: ofc. Go ahead and edit your question

Comment: the boolvalue is  the vales comeing from checkboxes  when i click on a check box a set of data is getting added so when i uncheck a check box i want to remove the  data entry from it

Comment: i have updated as u asked but new entrys are getting enterd in the console  for ur easyness i have added a working code sand box

Comment: in the code sand box click on the head text u can see the checkboxes

Comment: and in console i have console loged the  datastate